# How to INSERT into database for each element of array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a booking system and need to insert the details into mysql database. All of my variables are strings and one of them is an array - so I need to insert the same information for each array element ($ticketnumber). I have tried doing it with  a foreach loop, but it doesn't seem to work. How do I do this with only one INSERT statement as people may choose different number of tickets to buy?

Here is part of the code:

```
<?php

$day = $_SESSION['date'];
$time = $_SESSION['time'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$ticketnumber = $_REQUEST['tickets']; //this is the array variable

foreach ($ticketnumber as $ticket){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$name', '$day', '$time', '$ticket');";
    $handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $handle->execute();

}
?>
```

The values of my array in this case are(it varies depending on how many tickets you check):

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "010" [1]=> string(3) "011" }
```

This matched the value of `$ticket` as well, why is that happening?

My session and connection to the database are established before this. I also tried replacing the array variable with a string and the insert statement works.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You are closing the connection after the first iteration. Close it after the _loop_. You are directly passing user input to your DB which is open to SQL Injection. Read up on PDO. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: _"My session and connection to the database are established before this."_ - and where are you _re_-establishing the database connection, after you for some reason decided to `null` it ...?

Comment: `$ticket` is still an array in the loop i would expect you to be using `$ticket['value']` in the query

Comment: @nogad - don't think that's quite right but it is impossible to tell without seeing the data structure.

Comment: Hi, sorry, connection=null was outside my loop in my code, my mistake.

Comment: Did the posted answer work for you? If so, can you please accept it? If not, please post what _$_REQUEST['tickets']_ looks like.

Comment: @waterloomatt Hi, unfortunately, it did not work. Here is the value of my array:array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "014" [1]=> string(3) "015" [2]=> string(3) "016" } where the values are transfered from chosen checkboxes. I got this error, but still need to check it out online: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: @Codingnooby If you used the code from my answer, be sure that the names in the params array match the names of the placeholders exactly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate values into the SQL string as you are doing, there's not much benefit to using a prepared statement. Instead, prepare a statement with placeholders and execute it repeatedly for the various different values.

Create an array of parameters

```
$params['day'] = $_SESSION['date'];
$params['time'] = $_SESSION['time'];
$params['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Create the prepared statement with placeholders where your values will be bound

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (:name, :day, :time, :ticket);";
$handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Execute the statement in a loop for each value in `$ticketnumber`.

```
$ticketnumber = $_REQUEST['tickets'];

foreach ($ticketnumber as $ticket) {
    $params['ticket'] = $ticket; // assign the current ticket to the array of values
    $handle->execute($params);   // the values are bound to the prepared statement
}
```

You don't really need to explicitly close or null the connection (especially not inside the loop as others have pointed out).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution, it looks great, but I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - pointing at the line of the execute statement.

Comment: Be sure that the keys in the `$params` array match the names of the placeholders in the prepared statement exactly, and that there's _nothing else_ in `$params` besides those four key/value pairs. You can `var_dump($params)` it before using it in `execute()` or use your debugger to double check.

Comment: I did var_dump on them, and it all looks fine. I feel like it's only the array causing the problem.It's also showing the - Notice: Array to string conversion - at the execute line of the loop.

Comment: That seems strange. In order for you to get that notice, one of the elements of `$params` must have been an array, but if you did `var_dump($params)` directly before `$handle->execute($params);`, it should have showed if one of the elements of `$params` was an array rather than a string.

Comment: $param['ticket'] is still displaying as an array from the var_dump and has the values which came from $ticketnumber.

Comment: So `$ticketnumber` is an array, but each `$ticket` is also an array? What's in them?

Comment: The same values as in the $ticketnumber - the different codes of the tickets that were chosen with the checkboxes.

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you're saying that while you're iterating `$ticketnumber`, each element contains `$ticketnumber`, so I must not be understanding you correctly. Can you edit the question to show the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST['tickets'])`?

Comment: Hi, you understood correctly and I just doublechecked after you said that: my array var_dump: array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "010" [1]=> string(3) "011" }  and here is the var_dump of the variable that I define in the loop: array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "010" [1]=> string(3) "011" }  - they are eaxctly the same. I edited my question anyway.

Comment: Don't Panic, thank you very much for all your help, I think I found a way to fix this, just need to test it out. I have accepted your answer as it was a great one for what I initially asked.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. I'll admit I was stumped.